# Elastic scattering between particles and forces

Tags: particle-physics, scattering, dark-matter

If a WIMP interacts elastically with a nucleus, for which force they interact? Weak force? The same for neutrons, it interacts via strong force? The only elastic scattering i know is the Rutherford scattering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIMP is an acronym of [Weakly Interacting Massive Particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles), so it is a tautology to say that their interactions are with a weak force. This could be the electroweak force, or any other in more advanced grand unified models, elastically or inelastically the first order, i.e. higher probability , Feynman diagrams are with the carriers of that force.

The neutron is not an elementary particle, it is composed of quarks and a sea of antiquarks quarks and gluons (analogous to [the proton here)](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) . If you are asking of WIMP neutron elastic scattering, it will be with the appropriate weak force. If you are asking neutron +X elatic scattering, it will depend of what X is. If it is another hadron composed out of quarks and antiquarks it will be the strong force.

Comment: I forgot to add an information, I meant nuclear recoil not ordinary elastic scattering, is the same thing?

Comment: @abbba sure, elastic scattering leads to recoil, of whatever type.

Comment: The neutron may also interact weakly with other hadrons  too, plus it has an extremely weak interaction electromagnetically.

Comment: @Triatticus of course, quarks interact weakly too,but considering the enormous difference in the coupling constants between strong an weak,the weak is insignificant in neutron scattering.

Comment: I'm merely stating for completeness of course